# problem with '/' in the REST URL parameters for an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, encoding

```
var url     = relativeURI+'/rest/PPS/Prod/'+encodeURIComponent(prod)+'/Section/'+encodeURIComponent(section);

$j.ajax({
  url: url,

  type: 'POST',

  error: function(){
    alert('Error');
  },
  success: function(){
   alert('ItWorks');
  }
});

}
```

In this ajax call, if I have '/' in the parameters prod or sec, then there is an error. The request does not even hit the server. I am using the encodeURIComponent over the parameters. It works fine for other parameters that do not have '/' in them. Please help.

Comment: Do you want the slashes to end up being actual separators in the URL, or do you want them to be treated as part of each *part* of the URL?

Comment: I want the slashes present in the parameters 'prod' or 'section' NOT to be treated as URL separators.
For example..
my URI is
/.../rest/PPS/Prod/{B39}/Section/{PVT/SSS/F}

added the curly braces to signify the parameters.
After the use of encodeURIComponent() I get the URI like
/.../rest/PPS/Prod/{B39}/Section/PVT%2FSSS%2F

But this is failing. I get an error. where as other parameters having no slashes in them work well.

Comment: Well what error do you get? Is the error from the browser or from your server?

Comment: I have tested sending a request to the server with the encoded URI using 'REST Easy' and it works fine. jQuery ajax somehow throws the error.

Comment: I am sure that the request does not to go the server. I get alert from this part of the code . 
error: function(){
    alert('Error');
  }

Comment: Why not simply remove "/" or replace them with a more friendly URL character, like "-"?

Comment: @Ektron the whole point of `escapeURIComponent` is to make those characters "more friendly".

Comment: @srila can you tell us what exactly the error looks like?  Do you see the error in Firebug or the IE debugger?  edit - oh wait I see what you're saying now.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Firebug console?  That should show you the HTTP information for your Ajax requests, so that would help a lot.

Comment: Cannot :( because am trying to automate a process that deals with data having '/'

Comment: @Pointy : I am using safari. Never used Firebug console before. Is there any other way I could print the HTTP information from within the code?

Comment: The URL spec does permit escaped chars (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738), so escapeURIComponent should work for the URL. The problem may be with the mapping. The escaped characters are probably unescaped prior to invoking the REST method.

Comment: tried printing the status code and got 400

Comment: So your server doesn't like the URL.  Perhaps the server is not decoding the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your logic and the request does go to the server.  However, if the server doesn't like the URL, then your server side code won't even get called.  (In my case, there was no server side code, but I can see the 404 response and can see that the server -- Apache -- decoded the URL).

So perhaps your server can't decode the URL.  Are you sure that you encoded it when you tried the non-jquery route?  You might not need the `encodeURIComponent` calls.  What happens if you remove them?

Answer (score 0):

I have encoded the parameters and tried the non-jQuery route where it works fine ( Was using RESTEasy). When i remove the slashes, then I get 404 response, which means that there is no REST method with that URI.